# Sketchup Ruby API reference to deleted Face

Tags: ruby, sketchup

Hi all

I want to create a Sketchup tool for moving vertexes in a polygon (It is the same as move tool in sketchup ,except it just move vertex, not edge) . This polygon is in an array of polygon.

I created a "Tool" class, and when i pick the first vertex of one, move it to another position, and the appropriate polygon is created , replace the old polygon in array. But when i pick one vertex second time, ruby console display an error: reference to deleted Face

.
Here is my class. I have implemented this tool in there function : onMouseMove, onLButtonDown, draw.

```
class MoveVertexPolygon
   # an array of polygon
   def gridview
      @gridview
   end
   def gridview=(g)
     @gridview=g
   end

   def initialize
     @polygon = nil
     @bSelected = false
     @arr_vertex = []
     @drawn = false
     @pos= -1
  end

def onLButtonDown(flags, x, y, view)
   #if user don't click any vertex before.
   if(@bSelected == false)
     ip = view.inputpoint x,y
     selected_x = ip.position.x.to_f
     selected_y = ip.position.y.to_f
     pt = Geom::Point3d.new(selected_x, selected_y, 0)

     #get appropriate polygon position in array of polygon 
     @pos = @gridview.getIndexByCoordinate(selected_x,selected_y)
     #reset array of vertex
     @arr_vertex.clear

     #get polygon with given position
     @polygon = @gridview.array_element[@res].polygon

     #select a vertex
     if(@polygon != nil && @polygon.valid? && @polygon.is_a? Sketchup::Face)
        type = @polygon.classify_point(pt)
        if(type == Sketchup::Face::PointOnVertex)
           i = 0
           while( i < @polygon.edges.length)
               @arr_vertex.push(@polygon.edges[i].vertices[0].position)
               if(pt == @polygon.edges[i].vertices[0].position)
                  @selectedVertexIndex = i
                  @bSelected = true
               end
              i = i + 1
           end;
        end
     end
  #if user selected vertex, move it to another position
  else
    @bSelected = false
    @drawn = false
    @gridview.array_element[@res].polygon = @polygon
  end
end

def onMouseMove(flags, x, y, view)
#if user select a vertex, then let's user choose a position of this vertex, display a temporary          #polygon
   if(@bSelected)
     @ip = view.inputpoint x,y
     view.invalidate
   end
end

def draw(view)
    if(@drawn == false)
       entities = view.model.entities

       temp_x = @ip.position.x.to_f
       temp_y = @ip.position.y.to_f
       pt = Geom::Point3d.new(temp_x, temp_y, 0)

       #delete all edges and face of @polygon
       i=0
       temp_array_edges = []
       while(i < @polygon.edges.length)
         temp_array_edges.push(@polygon.edges[i])
         i = i + 1
       end;
       len = temp_array_edges.length
       i=0
       while(i < len)
        entities.erase_entities temp_array_edges[i] 
        i = i + 1
       end;

       #draw polygon again
       @polygon = nil
       @arr_vertex[@selectedVertexIndex] = pt
       @polygon = entities.add_face @arr_vertex

     end
end
```

Error said that @polygon is Deleted Face.

Thanks for your helping

Comment: Need more info here. What's the full error message? When is `@polygon` a deleted face?

Comment: Also, you use a bulk method to erase induvidual enities inside a loop: `entities.erase_entities temp_array_edges[i]`, why don't you erase everything in bulk: `entities.erase_entities(temp_array_edges)` ?

Comment: I don't know what your requirements for this tool is, but I have made a tool for manipulating vertices: http://www.thomthom.net/software/vertex_tools/ (not free)

Comment: Why are you erasing entities in the `draw` event of your tool? That event is used to draw OpenGL instructions to the viewport. It's usually called many times a second, erasing entities, or creating them just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @thomthom: full error message: Error : #<TypeError: reference to deleted Face> at line code : while( i < @polygon.edges.length) in draw method.
My tool help user move one vertex of polygon (just vertex, not edges or face). It is like move tool in Sketchup . Its operation is same as Sketchup move tool operation (Choose a vertex by left-click it and drag mouse, the appropriate temporary polygon is displayed , and when user left-click again, a  polygon with new vertex is displayed (drag-drop).

Comment: It is OK when i move the first vertex successfully. But when i move second vertex, after i left-click to select it and begin drag mouse, the error is displayed on ruby console.

Comment: I use draw method for displaying temporary polygon when user drag mouse to some positions. I think  polygon value in draw method is saved in everytime user drag mouse( move mouse). And when user left-click again. polygon is updated with the newest vertex.

Comment: Thanks you, i replaced the loop for deleting edges with your code. It is OK. When i delete and create a new polygon again in draw method, i just want to update the polygon with newest vertex and display it as temporary polygon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of erasing and recreating the face constantly, simply transform the vertex to it's new position. `entities.transform_by_vectors` will let you do that.
http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/ourdoc/entities.php#transform_by_vectors

And if you want display anything temporarily while using your tool, use `view.draw` to draw to the viewport.

You really should avoid doing anything other than drawing to the viewport in the `draw` event.